# Accurate output of Flyback converter

Tags: converter, flyback

I am currently designing a isolated power supply based on a flyback converter with the MAX17690. I am using this ic because I cannot add feedback for my application. However, in the design the voltage tolerance I am getting is not accurate enough for my application (it specified to be +/-5% and due to winding ratio errors this can get even worse). I am considering adding an additional step down converter after the Flyback converter to provide an accurate output voltage. This seems like a bit of a detour since I am cascading converters. Is this something that is more often in real-life applications or am I looking for a different type of solution. Hope you can give me some insight into how this problem of voltage accuracy is tackeled.

Added:
THe datasheet for the converters I am now using:
Flyback:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX17690.pdf
Step-down:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr51420.pdf?ts=1678044802294

Simplified schematic:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you add feedback? Please link the data sheet for the maxim part and add a schematic of your design as it currently stands.

Comment: Due to required isolation distances adding feedback is very complicated

Comment: I have seen a few systems which use a cheap flyback to give an isolated supply followed by a decent buck converter to give a nice reliable voltage rail. But 5% isn't a tight requirement, and should be possibly using fly-backs without too much challenge. Then I read you can't do feedback. Why not? Lots of devices measure feedback from the orignal transformer so you don't need to add extra deices or route lines etc. Such as LT8306 or the MAX17693A, why won't they work for you?

Comment: how big is the isolation distance? You did make a transformer with enough isolation. It can't be too big for, say, an optical fiber.

Comment: My desired output voltage would preferably be in the +/-2% range. My minimum separation distance is 2mm DTI.

Comment: I'm still not seeing what's wrong with using no-opto fly backs.

Comment: The voltage output accuracy is just too large for the power application that I am searching. The output current needs to be 2A, and the flyback converters that I found could only deliver this without feedback for 5% accuracy

Comment: While it wouldn't be appropriate for the voltage, just as example, I've used a LNK623 which uses primary side transformer voltage sensing and has way more accurate DC output than it deserves to (designed for 12V output, measured 12.0-12.6V under light to full load).

Comment: I would also be interested to see the circuit, as well as the transformer drawing. 2mm (Distance Through Insulation?) is incredible for a flyback transformer; I would expect resonant at that point. (For which, regulation could be by ferroresonant means, actually, but a post-reg wouldn't be awful either.)

Comment: The secondary rectification diode alone is going to eat up that 2% tolerance just going from minimum to maximum load. It's just not realistic to get this accuracy without feedback.

Comment: Yes thats just exactly what I have noticed, for that reason the solutions of using a second regulator. So there are no major drawbacks? Efficiency is not my highest priority. You are right that 2mm distance creates quite some leakage inductance which greatly reduces the efficiency and the power consumption by the snubber circuit. But as efficiency is not the primary concern this was acceptable. As I understand from the comments until now that 2% voltage accuracy without the use of secondary side feedback is not realistic without the post regulation?